# timefold optaplanner score calculation

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

regarding to the Cloud Balance example, what happens if instead of having  processes that should be located located into computers we have to put applications that use processes? I mean, 1 App is composed by various resources (sockets, java apps, etc) each one with it’s own characteristics (as in the example), but now we have to put apps into computers. The domain is easy to model but I’m not able to put/write a valid score, any help please?

[Domain Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmZCI.png)

I have try to model a score but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Currently this question is unanswerable. Please provide the requirements and the code you tried for *one* of your constraints, with clarity and in isolation.